# Passing arguments down recursive functions

Tags: python, recursion, closures, scope

I want to pass an argument from the first call of a recursive function down to the later ones:

Example:

```
def function(x):
    if base_case:
        return 4
    else:
        return function(x_from_the_first_call + x_from_this_call)
```

Is there any better way of doing this than a closure?

E.g.

```
def function(outer_x):
    def _inner(x)
        if base_case:
            return 4
        else:
            return function(outer_x + x)
    return _inner(outer_x)
```

Comment: Can you just make your function accept two arguments?  Then just pass the two values separately (with a default value for the initial call) and add them inside the function.

Comment: @BrenBarn Would you consider that cleaner than a closure? My problem with doing that is it causes there to be an extra parameter which could confuse anyone calling the function who is unaware of the implementation, which strikes me as a bad thing.

Comment: I usually do it with a separate named argument that defaults to `None`.  And "since we're all consenting adults" in python, presumably any caller who changes that arg has a good reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you will change x somehow in function, then this should work i think:

```
def function(x, *args):
    if base_case:
        return 4
    else:
        new_x = x+1 # some change to x

        if args:
            # in args all previous x values

        # remove if in case if you need all previous values
        if not args:
            args.append(x)

        return function(new_x, *args)
```